# What's a word for "someone who uses their position of power to make another person sell something they own for a lesser value"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

What word(s) can I use to describe someone who uses their position of power to make another person sell something they own for a lower value?

I've thought *coercing* or *forcing* but there must be a better word that I'm not getting.

Clarification:

The specific context here is a big European football club forces smaller clubs to sell their players for less than the market value. So the smaller clubs essentially undersell their assets out of coercion.

What word or idiom can be used to describe this practice by the big club?

Comment: *Coerce* is certainly what came to mind. Please read the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/544562/edit) to include the information requested. In particular, **why** are *coerce* and *force* not suitable, and what else have you looked up as their synonyms and rejected (and why did you reject those words)? What are your criteria for "better"?

Comment: @Anton Does the question require a noun or an adjective as an answer? It's not clear. The title of the question contradicts the body of the question. If it's looking for an adjective, it remains unexplained why *coercion* was rejected. (If it's looking for a noun, obviously "coercioner" is not a word.) Still, I agree that this shouldn't have been immediately closed without giving the person asking it a chance to clarify.

Comment: Here’s another thing that’s unclear about the question: If Fred forces George to sell something he owns for less than the market value, then Fred is, for want of a better word, a bully.  If Fred forces George to sell something he owns ***to Fred*** for less than the market value, then Fred is, perhaps, an extortionist.  Which scenario is the question asking about?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Also the question might be clearer if it said what kind of force is involved.  I guess it doesn’t mean physical assaults (or threat thereof). I doubt that it means having agents infiltrate the organizations of the smaller clubs and perform the sales transactions without the owner’s knowledge. Is it blackmail (threatening to publish secret, adverse information)?  What is the *nature* of the “power” that is being wielded? I’m sorry if you want to keep the question general / vague, but ISTM that it would benefit from a little more focus.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the question has been edited, it is far more specific, and it is not limited to asking for a single word. Can you please reopen it? May I remind everyone that the OP is a newcomer and needs time to understand the community. As a first effort, it's a valid and on topic question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I pointed to the tag checklist, which includes "Does the question list which words you didn't like, and why they aren't suitable?" The word *coercion* actually appears in the question. Why is that not suitable? What are the criteria for "better"? I don't believe it should be re-opened. The bar for this sort of question is high. It's been raised over the years, and for good reason.

Comment: @AndrewLeach the OP is a new contributor, in my experience the community also shows flexibility on first posts–if they are on-topic, and show *some* effort. The OP's comment has been deleted, probably when their question was edited, but perhaps by now they feel "unwelcomed"? There are four reopen votes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure what you mean by "The OP's comment has been deleted" as the single deleted comment was written by someone else (and self-deleted). I don't believe this question should be re-opened, because there is not enough information provided in order to write an answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach wasn't it the OP who said in a comment that the situation was a big football club trying to **squeeze** (my expression/answer!) **the small club** into surrendering their best players. Was it written by someone else? Did I imagine seeing it, when I edited the post for clarity? I don't think I did.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP's only addition was their edit (which was the correct thing to do, rather than add a comment) and you can see the edit history. I don't believe this question should be re-opened, because there is not enough information provided in order to write an answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Oops my bad, the "comment" was in actual fact the OP's edit. It may lack *some* information but there's enough to work on. Go on, soften up a little. *Please?*

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I like SWRs just fine, and I would happily cast the fifth vote to reopen, but three people (Andrew, Jason and I) have asked clarifying questions, and the OP has not responded to any of them. And if the OP has disengaged (run away) because they feel unwelcome, then there’s no point in reopening the question, because they won’t see any new contributions.